# manually inserting text in uisearchbar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, custom-keyboard

I need some help.

I have implemented a custom keyboard in my app on a `UIView` which stays of screen and slides up from bottom when user taps on the search bar. **I am not using a keyboard target or extension.**

The real question is how to insert text in `UISearchBar` when the user will press a button in my custom made keyboard. `UITextDocumentProxy` is not working here.

BTW I am developing in swift and I have added the `UISearchBar` using `UISearchBarController` programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text` property of `searchBar` to set the text on `Button` action of your custom keyboard.

```
self.searchController.searchBar.text = "\(sender.titleLabel.text)"
```

OR

```
self.searchController.searchBar.text = "\(self.searchController.searchBar.text)\(sender.titleLabel.text)"
```

Comment: I should have tried at least before posting this question lol. Thanks anyway.